# Is it possible to run Calabash on an iOS 10 device with Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, calabash, calabash-ios

I am using Xcode version 7.3.1. Calabash version is 0.17.1. I run our tests on a real device. I've downloaded the developer's disk image from Xcode 8 beta and have it copied in Xcode 7 and have enabled UIAutomation on the device running iOS 10. I see the device and the correct target specified in Instruments.

However, when I try to launch the Calabash test server the tests are not executed and eventually will timeout with the connection error.

```
Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError:

  "Timed out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError.
```

Is it not possible to run Calabash in Xcode 7 against a device running iOS 10? Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Calabash doesn't support Xcode 8 and iOS 10 at the moment because UIAutomation is no longer supported in Xcode 8. It looks like they are working on a replacement called "DeviceAgent" that is based on XCUITest.

Keep an eye out for this [calabash post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/g34znf0LnE4). They will update any progress they've made for iOS 10 support.